# Gradle Android rootProject.configurations vs configurations

Tags: android, gradle

My task is defined inside app/build.gradle

rootProject.configurations has no configuration while configurations has everything e.g. "implementation", "testImplementation" etc.

Why?

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 5.4.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2019-04-26 08:14:42 UTC
Revision:     261d171646b36a6a28d5a19a69676cd098a4c19d

Kotlin:       1.3.21
Groovy:       2.5.4
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.13 compiled on July 10 2018
JVM:          1.8.0_191 (Oracle Corporation 25.191-b12)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.14.6 x86_64
```

Answer (score 0):

The `build.gradle` file in the `app` folder defines a sub module (or sub project). The `build.gradle` file in the root folder defines the root project.

The configurations are added by plugins and in most use cases there is no need to apply a plugin in the root project.